# Is it possible to throttle the iCloud photostream sync in OS X?

Tags: macos, network, icloud, photo-stream

I have a large iCloud photo library. Once in a blue moon my iMac running Yosemite decides to forget all about the synced libraries, and I have to re-enable the iCloud streams. However, my little DSL line will then be clogged for hours on end, because OS X downloads gigabytes of pictures.

Is it possible to throttle the speed to a certain setting, say 1MBit/sec? Or at least to pause the sync, without having to re-download everything?

Comment: I have the same question. Just updated to the new Photos app, and I chose to use iCloud Photo Library for the first time. I now have my upload pipe completely saturated with 15GB of photos, and while that's not huge, it's still going to take the entire day to upload, and it's stalling my other network-related apps. (Email, Skype, etc.) Sure, I can turn off the computer - but I'd really like to *use* it right now...

Comment: Ok, now it's official: with the new photos app, the stream is really annoying. :) A throttle would be soooo appreciated now.

Comment: An update - the new Photos app allows you to pause the uploading in the Preferences. Pretty nice. (Photos -> Preferences -> iCloud)

Answer (score -1):

You can't. :(

I solved with QOS on the DSL Modem. (ASUS)

Comment: Hi Kintaro, welcome to Ask Different. Please explain how you solved it with QoS, as it may be a good alternative to the apparent inexistence of an in-app throttle. Thanks!